# Get ID from one table and insert it into another table

Tags: php, mysql

So basically, the users gonna input the students ID, first name, last name, teacher's first name and teacher's last name. I want to get the ID which is corresponding to the teacher's first and last name.

Here's My Code:

```
$get_teacher = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM teachers WHERE first_name = '$teacher_first_name' AND last_name = '$teacher_last_name'");

$get_teacher_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($get_teacher);

$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO students (student_id, first_name, last_name, teacher_id) VALUES ('$student_id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$get_teacher_arr[0]');");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in one query

```
INSERT INTO students (student_id, first_name, last_name, teacher_id) 
SELECT $student_id, '$first_name', '$last_name', id 
FROM teachers 
WHERE first_name = '$teacher_first_name' 
AND last_name = '$teacher_last_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do can do this in one query:

```
INSERT INTO students (student_id, first_name, last_name, teacher_id)
    SELECT $student_id, t.id, t.first_name, t.last_name
    FROM teachers t
    WHERE first_name = '$teacher_first_name' AND last_name = '$teacher_last_name';
```

First note:  Don't use variables stuffed into the string.  Learn how to use parameters in your query.  You are using mysqli_, so that is the right approach.

Second note:  You should be including the student's name as well.  You can do that using an update.

Third note:  Don't repeat the teachers' names in the `students` table.  A key reason for normalizing the database and having separate entities is to avoid storing the same data in multiple places.  So, your query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO students (student_id, teacher_id)
    SELECT ?, t.id
    FROM teachers t
    WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?;
```

Then you can fetch the teacher's names using a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Query on 3 table:

```
SELECT  s.first_name, 
        t.id_tea
FROM    (student s
        INNER JOIN st_te st ON s.id_stu = st.id_stu)
INNER JOIN teacher t ON st.id_tea = t.id_tea;
```

3 table:

```
student                  st-te                    teacher
id_stu  first_name       id  id_stu  id_tea       id_tea   first_name
1        John             1    1       1           1       Asher
2        Elsa             2    2       2           2       Lea
```

Query output:

```
first_name     id_tea
John            1
Elsa            2
```

All SQL for database and tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE student_teacher;
CREATE TABLE student (id_stu INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE teacher (id_tea INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE st_te (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, id_stu INT, id_tea INT);
```